# Is there some way to not to repeat a node in this code flow?

Tags: oop, uml

I've tried to use **Activity**  **Diagram** to depict this [pseudo-]code:

```
get expression
    while match '('
        get expression
        if !match ')'
            error
    get term
```

see:

[image]

Is there a way to depict that code without repeat `get expression` node twice?

Or I'm using a wrong diagram do depict that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is wrong. You're traversing `get_expression` twice in each iteration. Add a node below the first `get_expression` and the bottom [yes] would go to that new node.

[image: Modified UML]